# Implement non-generic interface using generic class

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous

I have custom control and I have interface this control exposes to it's users.

```
public interface ILookupDataProvider
    {
        void GetDataAsync(string parameters, Action<IEnumerable<object>> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onError);
    }
```

Need to implement it like so:

```
public class LookupDataProvider<T> : ILookupDataProvider
    {

        public void GetDataAsync(string parameters, Action<IEnumerable<T>> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onError)
        {
            var query = new EntityQuery<T>();
            this.entityManager.ExecuteQueryAsync(
                query,
                op =>
                    { 
                        if (op.CompletedSuccessfully)
                        {
                            onSuccess(op.Results);
                        } 
                        else if (op.HasError)
                        {
                            onError(op.Error);
                        } 
                    });
        }
    }
```

So, how do I tell that this generic method is really implementation of interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the class to be a generic method you could do this:

```
public class LookupDataProvider : ILookupDataProvider
{

    public void GetDataAsync<T>(string parameters, Action<IEnumerable<T>> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onError)
    {

    }

    void ILookupDataProvider.GetDataAsync(string parameters, Action<IEnumerable<object>> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onError)        
    {
         this.GetDataAsync<Object>(parameters, onSuccess, onError);
    }

}
```

**Edit**
In regards to Kirk's comment you need to move the type parameter on the method. While you could leave it on the class as well that can lead to interesting things. Run this code for example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new Foo<Guid>();
        b.Bar();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}



public class Foo<T> 
{

    public void Bar<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar<T>() : " +typeof(T).Name);
    }

   public void Bar()        
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Bar() : " + typeof(T).Name);
        this.Bar<string>();
    }

}
```

This actually is a warning (and I'm surprised it's not considered an exception)

Comment: I think this is the right solution -- except, why make the change that the class no longer takes the generic parameter?

Comment: but my point was that you could leave the type parameter in the class yet still use explicit interface implementation, as you've done in your original answer.  I'm not saying that's better per se, but it involves changing the OP's original code less, which seems best.

Comment: Isn't the "var query = new EntityQuery<T>();" difficult to do when the type is Object?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on ILookupDataProvider.  Select `Implement Interface`.  Fill out the method provided without changing the signature.

---

Edit: I thought someone would come on here and show you how to forward the call.  Oh well.

```
public class LookupDataProvider<T> : ILookupDataProvider 
{
  public void GetDataAsync(
    string parameters,
    Action<IEnumerable<object>> onSuccess,
    Action<Exception> onError)
  {
    Action<IEnumerable<T>> onSuccessGeneric = x => onSuccess(x.OfType<object>());
    this.GetDataAsync(parameters, onSuccess, onError);
  }

  public void GetDataAsync(
    string parameters,
    Action<IEnumerable<T>> onSuccess,
    Action<Exception> onError) 
  { 
    // as you had it before.
  } 
}
```

if you want the forwarding method to only be accessible through the interface, use this method signature:

```
  public void ILookupDataProvider.GetDataAsync(
    string parameters,
    Action<IEnumerable<object>> onSuccess,
    Action<Exception> onError)
```

Answer (score 1):

The type parameter doesn't have any bearing one way or another on the derived class being an implementation of the interface.

for instance:

```
interface I
{
  int X { get; }
}

class A : I
{
  int X { get; set; }
}

class B<T> : I
{
   void F(T t) {}
   int X { get; set; }
}
```

Bot A and B are implementations of I.

Comment: I think the point the OP is making is that because the signatures aren't compatible, the generic version isn't satisfying the interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on the interface and choose implement interface, it will do it for you, but the way you have the interface designed, it wont match the interface's definition.

To make them match, you can do the following (now the implementation will match the signature of the interface):

```
public interface ILookupDataProvider<T>
    {
        void GetDataAsync(string parameters, Action<IEnumerable<T>> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onError);
    }

    public class LookupDataProvider<T> : ILookupDataProvider<T>
```

Comment: +1 If you can change the interface to be generic as well this is ideal solution IMHO

Comment: @Josh, often, the whole reason I'm *using* an interface is to provide a *non-generic* means of accessing my API.  (for example, `IEnumerable` vs. `IEnumerable<T>`)